# Pdf generated using flying-saucer does not displays the text in specified font

Tags: flying-saucer

I am using flying-saucer to convert xhtml to pdf.
I have an xhtml in which a table is created.
The font family for the table content is declared as courier.
Pdf is generated using flying saucer for this xhtml.
The generated pdf does not displays the table content in courier font.
Attached is the input xhtml and screenshot of the generated pdf.
The code used for conversion from xhtml to pdf is:

```
    String inputFile = "samples/font.xhtml";
    String url = new File(inputFile).toURI().toURL().toString();
    String outputFile = "font.pdf";
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocument(url);
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(os);
    os.close();
```

What should be done to display the text in courier font ?

HTML input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
       <title>My First Document</title>
        <style type="text/css"> b { color: green; } </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
       <tr>
         <td style="font-family: courier;">Hello World</td>
       </tr>
        </table>
     </body>
 </html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The name of the font is case sensitive. It works with `font-family: Courier`.
You can also use `font-family: monospace`.